# Odd behavior doing join and

Tags: sql, sas

```
    create table umd2
    as select a.permno, a.date, a.realdate, exp(sum(log(1+b.ret))) - 1 as cum_return
    from msex2 (obs=50 keep=permno date realdate) as a, msex2 (obs=50 keep=permno date ret) as b
    where a.permno=b.permno and 0<=intck('month', b.date, a.date)<3
    group by a.permno, a.date
    having count(b.ret)=3;
```

This query is to calculate the momentum (cumulative return in the past 3 month of a stock). However, this gives me duplicate rows. I thought group by would not return duplicate rows?
When I added the realdate column to my group by statement,

```
    create table umd2
    as select a.permno, a.date, a.realdate, exp(sum(log(1+b.ret))) - 1 as cum_return
    from msex2 (obs=50 keep=permno date realdate) as a, msex2 (obs=50 keep=permno date ret) as b
    where a.permno=b.permno and 0<=intck('month', b.date, a.date)<3
    group by a.permno, a.date, a.realdate
    having count(b.ret)=3;
```

those duplicate rows disapear. Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the way that SAS behaves.  SAS recognizes the following query:

```
select a.permno, a.date, a.realdate, count(*)
from <whatever>
group by a.permno, a.date, a.realdate;
```

as being an aggregation query.  That means that the rows are aggregated and reduced, with one result row per combination of the three columns.  In particular, the non-aggregated columns in the `select` match (or are a subset) of the columns in the `group by`.

When you do this:

```
select a.permno, a.date, a.realdate, count(*)
from <whatever>
group by a.permno, a.date;
```

You are now using non-standard SQL.  Most databases would generate an error.  MySQL would accept this syntax, and assign an arbitrary value to `a.read_date` from the matching values.  SAS does something different.  SAS says:  "Well, you clearly don't intend for this to be an aggregation query."  So, it doesn't aggregate the *rows*, but it appends the aggregated values onto each row.  In other databases, you would do this using window functions.

Technically, SAS calls this remerging summary data, which is documented [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002473699.htm).

Comment: Very clear explanation. I never notice that I am doing something that is not standard.